# Mongoose doesn't update db entries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I use express.js with mongoose as ODM.

I know mentioned that when other serives do an update to mongoDB, mongoose doesn't recognize this. So still shows the old state of the database.

I think this is because mongoose uses a callback to get updated after creating, updating a new document but this callback doesn't get fired when another service interacts with mongoDB.

So how can I manuelly say mongoose to look after not own created documents?

**routes/user.js**

```
var User = require('../models/user.js')
, requirements = { enabled: true, expired: false, locked: false };

exports.list = function(req, res){
    User.find(requirements, function(err, users){
        res.send(users);
    });
};
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/users', user.list);
```

When I now access /users with curl or with the browser I am getting an array of all users in mongodb. Thats right until now. Now I register a new user over my PHP environment. When I now request /users again I still get the same array as before without the over php created user!

When I now restart the node service and request /users again the by php created user is there....

Comment: Your assertions about the Mongoose API not always reflecting the current state of the database are not correct.  The results of previous queries wouldn't reflect any outside changes made to the database since the queries were executed, of course, but any new `find` queries certainly would.  What's the specific case you're concerned about?

Comment: Sounds like the issue may be the view caching in express.js.  You could try `app.disable('view cache');` to see if this is the case.

Comment: This was it :). Is disabling the view cache the default behaviour when using node.js as communication API?

Answer (score 0):

The express.js framework includes view caching which is enabled by default for production sites).  I suspect your results are getting cached because you have included a function reference (user.list) rather than a closure, eg:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res){
    User.find(requirements, function(err, users){
        res.send(users);
    });
});
```

The view caching is a global setting and should only be caching the view template, not the contents of the view.  There was a request for [more granular caching](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/792) but it looks like this isn't required.

You can try disabling the view caching using:

```
app.disable('view cache');
```

A good resource to search or ask for clarification would be the [Express.js Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/express-js).